# Image not resolved. What is wrong?

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

Made Picture schema which contains attibutes to image for Webp and Jpeg.

- When I use that in Article and have a component link to it it works.
- When I use it in Article and have Embedded schema Paragraph and have a component link to Picture it works.
- When I use it in Article and have schema Contact as a component link and in that it as a component link to (same component) Picture **it is NOT RESOLVED**.

In CMS with preview page you have to see something like this:

"BinaryContent": {"Url": "/Preview/Images/my-contact.webp","FileName": "my-contact.webp","FileSize": 3332,"MimeType": "image/webp"

Other fields in that same schema are filled. So only the images is not present as BinaryContent.

DXA resolver is installed with depth 50.
Is it a wrong installation or .. ?

Comment: Sounds similar to this: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/why-doesnt-binarycontent-get-expanded-for-embedded-components

Comment: Thanks, Settting expandLinkDepth 2->3  fixed it in \100 Master\Building Blocks\Framework\Developer\Templates\DXA.R2\Render Page Content

Comment: Please Answer your own Question, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settting expandLinkDepth 2->3 fixed it.

\100 Master\Building Blocks\Framework\Developer\Templates\DXA.R2\Render Page Content